# TD contenteditable with autocomplete bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap-3

I spend my whole day for searching any autocomplete lib that support `contenteditable`. The closest that I found is jQuery UI which I tried but it conflicts with [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)( this is only my guess i'm not really sure ).

Is there any lib that will allow me to do this?

Note: if it is related I'm also using [dataTables](http://legacy.datatables.net/)

I will really appreciate it if someone give me a working example with this [fiddle ready](http://jsfiddle.net/azCnL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mouse click of any td why don't you dynamically add an input tag inside td. Which can make your cell editable.

If you are trying to implement something similar to excel data grid, try this:

suppose each cell (td) of your grid has a class - "cell" then,

```
$('.cell').click(function(){
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).html("<div class='editable' contenteditable='true'>"+text+"</div>");
});
```

I added class "editable" so that you can add any styling to it if required.

To move to next cell on tab you either need to bind 'keydown' and do the required action for tab or use tabindex property if your grid is made of divs

Comment: I'm not that good with jQuery but if the task is that simple maybe I can do it. But when the user press tab it should be go to the next tab. Most likely my task is like excel